# django item have bigger len after applying another filter

Tags: django, filtering, django-queryset

As showned bellow, I try to apply new filter to my idmatch queryset. But it return a new queryset with more objects than in the first one.

```
idmatch = IdMatch.objects.filter(idsport=idsport)
idmatchcount = idmatch.count()

idmatch_liematch = idmatch.filter(match__isnull=False)
count = idmatch_liematch.count()

print(idmatchcount, count)
605 634
```

I don't understand how it can be possible that I got a bigger lenght after applying a new filter.

The relation between IdMatch and Match is :

```
class IdMatch(models.Model):

    match = models.ManyToManyField(Match)
```

Ps : I check the 'idmatch_liematch' queryset and it got some pk witch are double... Do someone know why and if it is possible to do the same without any double pk.

Thanks

Comment: It will make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and thus some items might appear multiple times (the number of matches).

Answer (score 0):

It will make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and it will count for each `IdMatch`, the number of *related* `Match`es. This thus means that if an `IdMatch` links to two `Match`es, then it will be counted twice.

You can count the number of objects with [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

```
idmatch_liematch = idmatch.filter(match__isnull=False).distinct()
count = idmatch_liematch.count()
```

Comment: It's what I was thinking, thank you for the quick answer